# reset a select element

Tags: javascript, dom

how to make the first option selected? I tried this but doesnt work:

```
  selectElement.options[0].selected=true;
```

it gives me this error:

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

### update

solved! by defining selectElement correctly.

Comment: How have you defined `selectElement`?

Comment: it's my bad. I feel so stupid. selectElement refers to the element's value not the element itself. thanks for the hint.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this (See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qQzP2/))

HTML

```
<select id="selectElement">
    <option>First</option>
    <option selected>Second</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
selectElement.options[0].selected="selected";
```

Or you can do `selectElement.options[0].selected=true;`

Hope this works for you.

Comment: "Don't use `option.select = true`"? You're dead wrong. `HTMLOptionElement::selected` is a **boolean** property, not a boolean attribute. This is advantageous as using a boolean value will map the proper value from the property—in this case: `selected`—to the corresponding attribute.

Comment: I was referring it in context of HTML. Please refer [HTML <option> selected Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

Comment: HTML Attribute and DOM properties are very different things. See this link for more on `HTMLOptionElement::selected`: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-70874476

Comment: Just to clarify: `HTMLOptionElement::selected` will not map to an attribute. `HTMLOptionElement::defaultSelected` however, will.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('mySelect').selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: This is the way to do it! Much simpler and using a built in method of the select element.