# Reset select value to default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have select box

```
<select id="my_select">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b" selected="selected">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<div id="reset">
    reset
</div>
```

I have also reset button, here default (selected) value is "b", suppose I select "c" and after I need resert select box value to default, how to make this using jquery?

```
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
    // What do here?
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T8sCf/1/

Comment: If you want to reset the whole form, just call the built-in JavaScript  `.reset()` on the `<form>` element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reset a select element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141939/reset-a-select-element)

Comment: Also `<select>` has a `defaultSelected` which could be used in the function to reset if you just want a single element reset - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348042/javascript-defaultvalue-property-for-use-on-select

Comment: @andyb The first element is not necessarily the default selected value

Comment: @BrunoLM yes I take your point. I referenced the other question because it's very similar - "resetting a select value to default with JavaScript"

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can make use of the [`defaultSelected` property of an option element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement):

> Contains the initial value of the `selected` HTML attribute, indicating whether the option is selected by default or not.

So, the DOM interface already keeps track which option was selected initially.

```
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
    $('#my_select option').prop('selected', function() {
        return this.defaultSelected;
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T8sCf/26/)

This would even work for multi-select elements.

If you don't want to iterate over all options, but "break" after you found the originally selected one, you can use `.each` instead:

```
$('#my_select option').each(function () {
    if (this.defaultSelected) {
        this.selected = true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

---

Without jQuery:

```
var options = document.querySelectorAll('#my_select option');
for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
    options[i].selected = options[i].defaultSelected;
}
```

Comment: set your default option element with `defaultSelected` attribute and reset like this `$('#select option').removeAttr('selected');`

Answer (score 20):

```
$('#my_select').get(0).selectedIndex = 1;
```

---

But, In my opinion, the better way is using HTML only (with `<input type="reset" />`):

```
<form>
    <select id="my_select">
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b" selected="selected">b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>
    </select>
    <input type="reset" value="reset" />
</form>
```

- Check the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T8sCf/11/).

Comment: Any reason to use `get(0)` with `ID` selector?

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal No, just fast typing.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal `.get(0)` is used to obtain the DOM element so that you can access properties such as `.selectedIndex`

Comment: Instead of `$('#my_select').get(0)`, we can also use `$('#my_select')[0]` - *faster* typing.

Answer (score 15):

```
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
    $("#my_select").val('b');//Setting the value as 'b'
});
```

Comment: I don't know advanced what is default value in select box

Comment: @OTARIKI - if you dont know in advance what the default is, how do you know which option to add the `selected="selected"` attribute to?!

Comment: Right, so server-side you can still generate client-side code which knows the default!

Comment: its not resetting, its setting i think.

Comment: @Jamiec: It could, but it does not necessarily generate the JavaScript.

Comment: this might not work on some browsers. try triggering a `change()` after that : `$("#my_select").val('b').change()`

Answer (score 13):

Why not use a simple javascript function and call it on onclick event?

```
function reset(){
document.getElementById("my_select").selectedIndex = 1; //1 = option 2
}
```

Comment: what does it mean '1 = option 2' ?

Comment: JS counts selected indeces from 0. The first selected option would be selectedIndex = 0, the second option = 1, third option = 2, etc.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `data` attribute of the `select` element

```
<select id="my_select" data-default-value="b">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b" selected="selected">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

Your JavaScript,

```
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
    $("#my_select").val($("#my_select").data("default-value"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T8sCf/10/

***UPDATE***

---

If you don't know the default selection and if you cannot update the html,
add following code in the dom ready ,

```
$("#my_select").data("default-value",$("#my_select").val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T8sCf/24/

Comment: Finally, this worked for me thanks [ I am using Material Bootstrap ]

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
    $('#my_select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});
```

Comment: It won't work because selected 'b' is located on second position

Answer (score 5):

```
<select id="my_select">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b" selected="selected">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<div id="reset">
    reset
</div>

$("#reset").on("click", function () {
    $('#my_select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});
```

This is a simple way for your question. only one line answer.

Answer (score 4):

One nice clean way is to add a `data-default` attribute to the select

```
<select id="my_select" data-default="b">
...
</select>
```

An then the code is really simple:

```
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
    var $select = $('#my_select');
    $select.val($select.data('default'));
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/T8sCf/7/

Answer (score 3):

You can also reset the values of multiple SELECTs and then trigger the submit button.

Please see it here in action:

[Live Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/iam777/m9g463k5/)

```
$(function(){
    $("#filter").click(function(){
        //alert('clicked!');
        $('#name').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        $('#name2').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        $('#submitBtn').click();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
    $('#my_select').val('-1');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T8sCf/1323/

Comment: short and simple as it should be!

Answer (score 3):

If you looking to reset, try this simply:

```
$('element option').removeAttr('selected');
```

To set desire value, try like this:

```
$(element).val('1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind an event handler to the focus event of the `select` to capture the previous value.  Then set the value of the `select` to the previous value when reset is clicked.

```
var previousValue = "";
$("#my_select").on("focus",function(){
    previousValue = $(this).val();
});

$("#reset").on("click", function () {
   $("#my_select").val(previousValue);
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/T8sCf/17/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
var preval = $('#my_select').val(); // get the def value

$("#reset").on("click", function () {
   $('#my_select option[value*="' + preval + '"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

[**checkout this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T8sCf/16/)

take a `var` which holds the default loaded value before change event then get the option with the attribute selector of value with holds the `var` value set the property to selected.

Comment: Instead of `$('#my_select option[value*="' + preval + '"]').prop('selected', true);`, you could just do `$('#my_select').val(preval)`.

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you out.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        $(function(){
            var defaultValue = $("#my_select").val();
            $("#reset").click(function () {
                $("#my_select").val(defaultValue);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="my_select">
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b" selected="selected">b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>
    </select>
    <div id="reset">
        <input type="button" value="reset"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The OP doesn't know which option will be selected by default.

Comment: On load of the page, a variable could be set based on the value that is selected by the app. The same variable could be used for setting the value on click of reset.

Comment: Maybe you should add that to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If using Spring forms, you may need to reset the selected to your options label. You would set your form:select id value to an empty string resets your selection to the label as the default.

```
<form:select path="myBeanAttribute" id="my_select">
    <form:option value="" label="--Select One--"/>
    <form:options items="${mySelectionValueList}"/>
</form:select>

 $("#reset").on("click", function () {
        $("#my_select").val("");
 });
```

in the case where there's a reset button. Otherwise

```
$("#my_select").val("");
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are working with Bootstrap-select, you might want to use this:

```
$('#mySelect').selectpicker('render');
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way that runs is

```
 var myselect = $("select.SimpleAddAClass");
 myselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
 myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```

Answer (score 1):

With jquery :

```
$("#reset").on("click", function() {
    $('#my_select').val($('#my_select').find('option[selected="selected"]').val());
}
```

Comment: It would be worth expanding on your answer to explain what the code does. Think about new users to jQuery who have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#my_select').find('option:not(:first)').remove();
```

Call this function each time before populating the **select**

Comment: What I have been looking for to reset the select widget - by removing all options

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
    $("#my_select option[selected]").prop('selected', true);
}
```

You find for the default option that has the select attribute and you change the selection to that option.

Answer (score 0):

Reset all selection fields to the default option, where the attribute selected is defined.

```
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
    // Reset all selections fields to default option.
    $('select').each( function() {
        $(this).val( $(this).find("option[selected]").val() );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to resolve it like the other answers unfortunately, I didn't get a right way to do it, once I tried as I write below:

```
$('#<%=ddID.ClientID %>').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
```

this code works for me, I hope that will be useful for you guys.

Best Regards.

Samuel Alvarado.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$('select')[0].value = "default vaule"
```

```js
function reset(){
  $('select')[0].value="default value"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="default value" >Default</option>
  <option value="1" >Value 1</option>
  <option value="2" >Value 2</option>
  <option value="3" >Value 3</option>
</select>
<button onclick="reset()" >Click</button>
```

Answer (score -3):

I have select box

```
<select id="my_select">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b" selected="selected">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<div id="reset">
    reset
</div>
```

I have also reset button, here default (selected) value is "b", suppose I select "c" and after I need resert select box value to default, how to make this using Angular2?

Comment: This is not the right way to ask questions. This is only for answers. For your query, please go to through ASK QUESTION button.

Comment: sorry. i am new user to this community. will post it in Ask Questions from next time