# How to uncheck checkbox on back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Hi I have numbers of check boxes and below that I have a Button, which will filter data as per check box selection..
[image]

When I will click on filter button it will transfer to other page and when I click on back button the checkbox reamains checked.

but I want that when I click on back button then checkbox should be uncheck.

[image]

Any help.

Comment: Retagged your question as this is not possible with pure HTML

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can reset the checkboxes on page load using jQuery

```
$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gCBru/) (Checkbox will be never checked as `onload` am getting rid of `checked` property)

`ondomready` (Place the below code anywhere in your document)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: I have already taken `<body onload="catalogue.sortByName()">`, how to use this at page load ?

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ Wait, I'll edit my answer, but for this you will need jquery library

Comment: Please note that [there is a better way to reset to the default value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16913094/218196) (in the general case).

Comment: @FelixKling Isn't that something which can be done using a simple `<input type="reset" value="Reset" />` or am missing something there?

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Well, it depends whether you want to do this programmatically (like in this case) or not. The point of my comment was that unchecking the checkboxes is not the same as resetting them, in the general case.

Comment: @FelixKling yea well, cuz sometimes it's funny when some users go for complicated approach rather than a simple one.. :) always happens with JS-CSS solutions..

Comment: True :) Btw, I just noticed that question I linked to is about a `select` elements but checkboxes have a similar property, called  `defaultChecked`.

Comment: @FelixKling Yea, I got confused cuz of that, so commented :)

Answer (score 28):

For those who have similar issues, add `autocomplete="off"` to checkbox might help.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thank you.

Comment: @ohkts11 Thank you very much. You're a hero.

Answer (score 2):

You may use below code :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
         //unchecked your check box here.  
      $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', false)
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this when back button is clicked 
Use Jquery to clear the checkboxes

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each( function() {
$(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```