# Clear form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the code below to reset all of my values on a particular form.

```
        $('#' + frm).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
        $('#' + frm).closest('form').find("input[type=password]").val("");
        $('#' + frm).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#' + frm + ' input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
```

It works fine for 95% of the cases but I would like to reset all of the Select box back to the selected index of 0.  If there is a better or more efficient to do this entire process to reset all element types I'm open to the best suggestion.  I need to reset the form because the same form will be used over and over again by the same person to add employment history.

Thanks for the input

Comment: `document.querySelector("form").reset()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Form reset() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp)

> The reset() method resets the values of all elements in a form (same
>   as clicking the Reset button).

```
 $('#' + frm).closest('form')[0].reset();
```

Comment: Is there something special that I must do when I create the select values in order for it to go back to 0.  the reset code is working great for everything else but not the selected values

Comment: I have  <option selected="selected" value="choose">Choose a degree</option> but it never gets reset to the either the default value or index 0

Comment: take a look on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913094/reset-select-value-to-default

Comment: to keep the selected value after reset you have to handle that with JS code

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own reset form method:

```
jQuery.fn.reset = function(fn) {
   return fn ? this.bind("reset", fn) : this.trigger("reset");
 };
```

This would allow you to attach a code to a reset function:

```
jQuery("#form").reset(function(){ 
   /* some other code */ 
 });
```

You can (and still this is recommended way to do the things) use a simple HTML input of type reset - it will do the same even on browsers who have JavaScript disabled.