# how to reset dropdownlist to default after open the bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

What I am trying to do is when the user opens the modal and select option from the dropdownlist and close it without doing anything and reopen it the dropdownlist become "--select--" again

```
<pre>
<div class="inpu_modal">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Add_interaction.with_name, new { @class = "sub-title alighn" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Add_interaction.with_name, new SelectList(ViewBag.names, "Value", "Text"), "--Select--", new { @class = "with", @autocomplete = "off" })
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger with_name_span"></span>
</div>
</pre>



function Open_new_interaction() {
        document.querySelector('.drug_name_span').innerHTML = null;
        document.querySelector('.with_name_span').innerHTML = null;
        document.querySelector('.Degree_span').innerHTML = null;
        $('.drug option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
        $('.with option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
        $('#Add_InteractionDrug').modal("show");
    }
```

Comment: I cannot comment on the code above because of my reputation points but, I'm assuming that the code you have now does not reset the the list to the "---select---"?
default option again.[You would have to manually do that with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16913242/15147229)

Comment: I tried the link it works with open new but when I am trying to edit on the same modal and select from the dropdown passed on the data returned from the backend something go wrong

Comment: $('.active_name option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
            $(".active_name option:contains(" + data.active_name + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Comment: I didn't get any error but the dropdownlist does not work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap modal, you must do this:

```
$( ".modal-class" ).on('shown', function(){
    //reset the  dropdown here, do all the reset logic here
    //check if select dropdown is not null, and then loop through and get the default and set the selected.
    //
   let dropDown = document.querySelector("#dropdownId");
   //if the default value is at index 0, then just
    dropDown.selectedIndex = 0;
   /*if not, then loop through the options and find the option by inner HTML(i forget 
    if it contains a value*/  
    //if it has a value)

});
```